# Which Prolog implementation uses this syntax?

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

I have to study Prolog for the AI course at school. My teacher uses Visual Prolog which is only available on Windows. I use MacOS so I downloaded SWI-Prolog thinking it's similar. However, I noticed that the syntax is not the same. For example: the keyword if is replaced by :- in SWI-Prolog, also my teacher used this syntax:

```
predicates  
  likes(symbol, symbol)   

clauses  
  likes(ellen, tennis).    
  likes(john, football).
```

which gives me an error in SWI-Prolog. What do I have to download to use the same syntax?

Comment: drop the whole **predicates** *section* and the **clauses** *keyword*

Comment: @CapelliC is there any Prolog implementation I can download that uses that syntax?

Comment: I think on MacOS you cannot find any... beware that Visual Prolog and SWI-Prolog have deeper differences than the superficial change I suggested

Comment: Visual Prolog is not a Prolog, it extends Prolog quite a bit. This is NOT about syntax. If you must use Visual Prolog on MacOS, you might as well use a VM with windows on it.